# Dynamic Iteration with arrays. Is it possible? if yes how?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, loops, nested-lists

What I am trying to achieve is a couple of nested loops, where the number of nests will be dynamic.
So if for example there is 2 nested loops needed for the program then it will go

```
for i in abc:
   for j in def:
       codes
```

So, if there is a need for 3 nested loops that is set by multiple conditions within the program, then the loop will be dynamically set, and that's what I don't know how to do or if it can be done. So I want it to be automatically do

```
 for i in abc:
       for j in def:
           for k in ggh:
               codes
```

So you can see I manually wrote the third nest, but can it be done automatically?
WITH PYTHON ...

Comment: A more concrete example of what you are trying to do would be helpful...

Comment: Try [intertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ***recursive*** function:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

def recursive_iter(list_):
    for i in list_:
        if isinstance(i, (list, tuple)):
            recursive_iter(i)
        else:
            print(i)

recursive_iter(l)
```